# Problema para depurar información con listView1.Items.RemoveAt()

Tags: c#

Que amigos  les comento estoy  depurando la información de la clase  Win32_NetworkAdapte con el método   listView1.Items.RemoveAt(); Como tengo varios adaptadores de red claramente la clase me va enviar información para cada uno de ellos por lo que para depurarla tengo que ir avanzando adaptador por adaptador,  pero al hacer esto genero muchas lineas de código ya que voy poniendo  listView1.Items.RemoveAt() por listView1.Items.RemoveAt() y estoy buscando la menara de que con un ciclo for pueda depurar mas rapido ¿ se puede?

```
private void MuestraInformacion8(String Key)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();


        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.Columns.Add("Propiedad");
        listView1.Columns.Add("Valor");

        try
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from " + Key);
            foreach (ManagementObject objeto in searcher.Get())
            {

                string grupo = objeto["Name"].ToString();
                listView1.Groups.Add(grupo, grupo);

                if (objeto.Properties.Count <= 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("La Información No Está Disponible", "No Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    return;
                }




                foreach (PropertyData PropiedadObjeto in objeto.Properties)
                {
                    ListViewItem listViewItem1 = new ListViewItem(PropiedadObjeto.Name);
                    if (PropiedadObjeto.Value != null && PropiedadObjeto.Value.ToString() != "")
                    {
                        listViewItem1.SubItems.Add(PropiedadObjeto.Value.ToString());
                    }
                    listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem1);
                    listView1.Groups[grupo].Items.Add(listViewItem1);
                }

            }

            listView1.Items.RemoveAt(13);
            listView1.Items.RemoveAt(12);
            listView1.Items.RemoveAt(11);
            listView1.Items.RemoveAt(10);
            listView1.Items.RemoveAt(9);
            listView1.Items.RemoveAt(8);
            listView1.Items.RemoveAt(7);
            listView1.Items.RemoveAt(6);
            listView1.Items.RemoveAt(5);
            listView1.Items.RemoveAt(4);
            listView1.Items.RemoveAt(3);
            listView1.Items.RemoveAt(2);
            listView1.Items.RemoveAt(1);
            listView1.Items.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se pueden obtener datos \n" + exp.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

Comment: que es depurar? y un for no funciona porque???

Comment: depurar quitar la información necesaria la que no ocupemos

Comment: y cual es el problema? no estaria entendiendo.

Comment: @JohnnyDroop veamos.... primero estás agregando elementos en el listView, y luego estás eliminando algunos en posiciones fijas... qué es lo que determina que tengas que eliminar un item???

Comment: Y no sería mejor usar una condición para solo agregar lo que necesitas??